# Migration from Nixops 1.7 to 2.0 and <deployment>.nix to nixops.nix

Tags: nixos

I try to migrate my `nixops` from version 1.7 to `nixops_unstable` 2.0.0-pre-7220cbd. After installing `nixops_unstable` I cannot work with the `nixops` command anymore:

```
$ nixops deploy -d streaming
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/nix/store/diamr11y34lkmnjwkyw5qnv5xcn1x60h-python3.9-nixops-2.0.0-pre-7220cbd/bin/.nixops-wrapped", line 9, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/nix/store/3ybyi0v3pj8hlchzcchsx3m2myjpbmir-python3-3.9.13-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nixops/__main__.py", line 56, in main
    args.op(args)
  File "/nix/store/3ybyi0v3pj8hlchzcchsx3m2myjpbmir-python3-3.9.13-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nixops/script_defs.py", line 710, in op_deploy
    with deployment(args, True, "nixops deploy") as depl:
  File "/nix/store/gwlgfywzqypv91rxw916v81mpzhckdz5-python3-3.9.13/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 119, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/nix/store/3ybyi0v3pj8hlchzcchsx3m2myjpbmir-python3-3.9.13-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nixops/script_defs.py", line 72, in deployment
    with network_state(args, writable, description=activityDescription) as sf:
  File "/nix/store/gwlgfywzqypv91rxw916v81mpzhckdz5-python3-3.9.13/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 119, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/nix/store/3ybyi0v3pj8hlchzcchsx3m2myjpbmir-python3-3.9.13-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nixops/script_defs.py", line 102, in network_state
    network = eval_network(get_network_file(args))
  File "/nix/store/3ybyi0v3pj8hlchzcchsx3m2myjpbmir-python3-3.9.13-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nixops/script_defs.py", line 60, in get_network_file
    raise ValueError(f"Neither flake.nix nor nixops.nix exists in {network_dir}")
ValueError: Neither flake.nix nor nixops.nix exists in /home/matthias/nixops
```

I guess the important part here is `ValueError: Neither flake.nix nor nixops.nix exists in /home/matthias/nixops`. That's correct, I never had `nixops.nix` but this deployment is defined in `/home/matthias/nixops/streaming.nix`.

For the moment I don't want to migrate to using flakes, I just try to get the existing way working with `nixops_unstable`.

Changing `streaming.nix` to `nixops.nix` does not work, probably because it cannot relate its existing state to this new file name, as the file is actually part of nixop's state:

```json
{
  "c54b29a1-417e-11eb-9873-0242cc6606ab": {
    "configsPath": "/nix/store/46s4g876yjdijfdjwpqqjzj94pyp05lz-nixops-machines", 
    "name": "streaming", 
    "nixExprs": "[\"/home/matthias/nixops/streaming.nix\"]", 
    "resources": {
      "styx": {
        "configsPath": "/nix/store/46s4g876yjdijfdjwpqqjzj94pyp05lz-nixops-machines", 
        "creationTime": "1608329862", 
        "index": "0", 
        "keys": "XXXXXXXX", 
        "none.sshPrivateKey": "XXXXXXXX\n", 
        "none.sshPublicKey": "XXXXXXXX", 
        "none.sshPublicKeyDeployed": "1", 
        "publicVpnKey": "XXXXXXXX", 
        "sshPinged": "1", 
        "state": "3", 
        "stateVersion": "20.09", 
        "targetHost": "styx.p7m.de", 
        "toplevel": "/nix/store/hjlv7mlp71rij4vn3dhvr6rxickldjaa-nixos-system-styx-22.05.915.9ff91ce2e4c", 
        "type": "none", 
        "vmId": "nixops-c54b29a1-417e-11eb-9873-0242cc6606ab-styx"
      }
    }, 
    "rollbackEnabled": "1"
  }
}
```

The documentation on migration I found is very sparse: https://nixops.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual/migrating.html. More or less I could only find, that I have to define `network.storage.legacy = {}` which does not solve my migration problem.

How do I change from `<deployment>.nix` to `nixops.nix`? How do I separate between different deployments, that I use to group similar servers?

Answer (score 0):

I got the conversion done by doing the following steps for each deployment:

1. I moved the file `${deploymentname}.nix` to `${deploymentname}/nixops.nix`
2. I exported all state using nixops 1.7: `nixops export -d ${deploymentname} > ${deploymentname}/state.json`
3. I updated the location of the moved file from step 1 in the `${deploymentname}.json` file (which is on key `nixExprs`)
4. I updated the configuration in `${deploymentname}/nixops.nix` where it references external files using relative paths.
5. I imported the state using nixops 2.0: `cd ${deploymentname}/ ; nixops import < ${deploymentname}.json`
6. I redeployed: `nixops deploy -d ${deploymentname}`